# Sum of all positive and negative numbers in string python

Tags: python

Sorry if this is a stupid question I am still very new to python but I was wondering,

If I have string,  s = '1+6.3+3-7.6'

how could I take the sum of that?

I have tried using isdigit() but that just gets all the digits
I have also tried turning it to a float but I got could not convert string to float
I also tried turning it into an integer but I got invalid literal for int() with base 10.

Comment: Have a look at the `eval()` function.

Comment: @Mole Using eval could be dangerous.